# How do I use the ES6 import function with a symbolic path to the source file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, ecmascript-6, ecma

I am trying to understand the ES6 import function better, and I need your help.

#### The Scenario

Let's assume that I have a subset of code within my application that is used frequently, and I arrange all that code into a folder so that it is together.

So now, in three separate files, I have something like the following (note: I'm using TypeScript, so the file names in the example end in '.ts'):

file0.ts:

```
import {AbstractCoreCommunicationClass} from '../../../core-packages/communication/abstract-core-communication'
```

file1.ts:

```
import {AbstractCoreCommunicationClass} from '../communication/abstract-core-communication'
```

file2.ts:

```
import {AbstractCoreCommunicationClass} from '../../../../../core-packages/communication/abstract-core-communication'
```

### My Hope

It is my hope that I could clean up these references to something like this:

file0.ts:

```
import {AbstractCoreCommunicationClass} from '@my-communication-core/abstract-core-communication'
```

file1.ts:

```
import {AbstractCoreCommunicationClass} from '@my-communication-core/abstract-core-communication'
```

file2.ts:

```
import {AbstractCoreCommunicationClass} from '@my-communication-core/abstract-core-communication'
```

### Things I have Tried

I know that in Laravel (a different framework) that modules can be created and loaded by editing one of the core loader definition files such as composer.json or the main config/app.php file.

I have looked for a similar kind of protocol that can be used in the package.json file to reference non-npm packages, but I have not found any such information. The closest information that I have found is a tutorial in which NPM explains how to use NPM private packages, which would accomplish the same goal as long as I want to pay $7/month for the rest of my life to have my package hosted on their servers.

There must be a way to handle this kind of package management locally, but I have not discovered what it is, and that is why I need YOUR help!

All help is appreciated. There are no wrong answers.  Even a bad answer can sometimes point me in the right direction, so give me your thoughts and let's figure this out together so that everyone can benefit!

Comment: How to interpret the module specifier is not part of the ECMAScript spec. It depends on the module loader your environment is using.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is specific to the language and the environment. It's currently impossible to address this issue with ES modules alone.

TypeScript allows to specify [`paths`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) configuration entry for path aliases.

Webpack allows to specify [`alias`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias) configuration entry for path aliases.
The same thing can be achieved in Rollup with a [plugin](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-alias).

NPM allows to specify [local dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths) without a need for a repository. There's also a number of solutions for local NPM repositories, e.g. [sinopia](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinopia).

Given that there is TypeScript project that installs NPM dependencies and is being built with Webpack, any of listed solutions is applicable.

Answer (score 2):

#### HOW TO USE LOCAL PACKAGES IN NPM

It turns out that NPM has a feature that allows me to do exactly what I need to do. I reread the package.json documentation after writing the question above and found that NPM now allows for a local file directory reference to a package.

#### How it looks in pacakge.json

I used npm to create the linkages (see next section), and then I inspected the package.json file to find the following:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    //###THIS IS MY NEW LINE###
    "data-structures": "file:src/app/medface/data-structures",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "ng2-cookies": "^1.0.12",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "showdown": "^1.8.0",
    "to-markdown": "^3.1.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
```

Notice how the `file:` string prepends the source. I then designed a unit test to load one of the files from this directory using the name I assigned.

```
import {VisitDataStructure} from 'data-structures/visit';

describe( "The data structure package", ()=>{
    fit("loads without failure and allows the user to import classes within the folder.", ()=>{
        let visit = new VisitDataStructure();
        expect(visit).not.toBeNull();
    } );
} );
```

The test runs with flying colors!

(Note: the function `fit` is just like `it`, except it tells the testing system that it should "focus" only on that one test and ignore all the rest.)

#### How to achieve this using npm

To achieve this local package reference setup, several things must occur in order.

Step 1: Create a package using `npm init`

Navigate to the sub-folder in the terminal and type `npm init` (this assumes that you are already using npm, as I am).

Follow the on screen prompts to create your package.json file. The file will ask for a name, this name is how you will refer to the package within your system. In my case, I assigned the name 'data-structures' to the test package.

#### Step 2: Install the sub package using `npm intall --save [pathToLocalFile]`

From the root of your application, the same folder that holds the package.json file for your whole application, find the relative path to your new folder.  In my case, it was `src/app/medface/data-structures`.

If your relative path is correct, then you should be able to use `ls` or `dir` to show a file at [relativePath]/package.json (linux/mac) or [relativePath]\package.json (windows)

Then run the command `npm install --save [relativePath]`.

You will see npm do its thing. If it gives you an error, read the error and go back to step #1.  (When I ran it the first time, I got an error and realized that I had to use `npm init` in the directory **before** I could install it).

**Note:** for the terminal command alternative, yes, you CAN use `npm install -S [relativePath]` -- it is the same command as above.

#### Step 3: Use your new package name in the code.

Now that it is installed, you can use the name you assigned anywhere within your code, and the package.json file will tell your pre-processor where to find the reference files.

GREAT WORK!  Now go do some awesome coding!